# Google pagespeed isn't acceping my image as optimized

Tags: image, performance, jpeg, performance-testing, image-optimization

I'm trying to make my images optimized for google pagespeed test. I have an image with 1200x393 dimensions. When I optimize the image with Photoshop, its size is approximately 250kb and with Corel it becomes 100kb. Google doesn't accept either. It says Compressing and resizing ... .jpg could save 92.6KiB (90% reduction).

[image: Photoshop screenshot]
[image: Corel screenshot]

How can I pass pagespeed test?

Answer (score 1):

From [Image Optimization](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/image-optimization):

> Image optimization boils down to two criteria: optimizing the number
>   of bytes used to encode each image pixel, and optimizing the total
>   number of pixels: the filesize of the image is simply the total number
>   of pixels times the number of bytes used to encode each pixel. Nothing
>   more, nothing less.
>
> As a result, one of the simplest and most
>   effective image optimization techniques is to ensure that we are not
>   shipping any more pixels than needed to display the asset at its
>   intended size in the browser. Sounds simple, right? Unfortunately,
>   most pages fail this test for many of their image assets: typically,
>   they ship larger assets and rely on the browser to rescale them -
>   which also consumes extra CPU resources - and display them at a lower
>   resolution. ...
>
> you should ensure that the number of unnecessary
>   pixels is minimal, and that your large assets in particular are
>   delivered as close as possible to their display size

Common error is to have big image in source and scale it down with `width` and `height` attributes on UI.